# How to map the result set of a JPA NativeQuery to a POJO using SqlResultSetMapping

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, pojo, sqlresultsetmapping

I am attempting to map the results of a Native query to a POJO using @SqlResultSetMapping with @ConstructorResult.  Here is my code:

```
@SqlResultSetMapping(name="foo",
    classes = {
        @ConstructorResult(
                targetClass = Bar.class,
                columns = {
                    @ColumnResult(name = "barId", type = Long.class),
                    @ColumnResult(name = "barName", type = String.class),
                    @ColumnResult(name = "barTotal", type = Long.class)
                })
    })

public class Bar {

private Long barId;
private String barName;
private Long barTotal;

...
```

And then in my DAO:

```
Query query = em.createNativeQueryBar(QUERY, "foo");
... set some parameters ...
List<Bar> list = (List<Bar>) query.getResultList();
```

I have read that this functionality is only supported in JPA 2.1, but that is what I am using.  Here's my dependency:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
```

I found a couple of resources, including this one: [@ConstructorResult mapping in jpa 2.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22423604/constructorresult-mapping-in-jpa-2-1).  But I am still not having any luck.

What am I missing?  Why can't the SqlResultSetMapping be found?

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown SqlResultSetMapping [foo]
```

Comment: in your example the pojo instance variable names don't match what you put in @ColumnResult.

Comment: If Bar isn't an entity, persistence annotations are not picked up as it isn't part of the persistence unit.  Put your annotation on an entity.

Comment: I would rather not have the overhead of dealing with an entity.  The JPA 2.1 spec provides for mapping directly to a POJO.  I just can't get it to work. See section ConstructorResult (JPA 2.1):  [link](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Querying).  Also see: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13012584/jpa-how-to-convert-a-native-query-result-set-to-pojo-class-collection). And: [link](http://mariemjabloun.blogspot.com/2014/05/jpa-mapping-native-query-to-bean-pojo.html)

Comment: Did you find the solution? I have similar problem

Comment: @Hexe, yes, the selected answer was the solution.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

`@SqlResultSetMapping` annotation **should not be put on a POJO**. Put it at (any) `@Entity` class. "Unknown SqlResultSetMapping [foo]" tells you, that JPA provider  doesn't see any mapping under name 'foo'. Please see another answer of mine for the correct example

- [JPA- Joining two tables in non-entity class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25179180/jpa-joining-two-tables-in-non-entity-class/25184489#25184489)

Comment: I don't understand why the Object needs to be an entity.  You say yourself that it does not need to: "Mapping to POJO class with @ConstructorResult was added in version 2.1 of JPA."

Comment: The Object you are mapping results to (`targetClass` of `@ConstructorResult`) doesn't have to be an Entity. However `@SqlResultSetMapping` has to annotate an Entity class. the reason is that JPA provider scans all Entity classes and can pick up `@SqlResultSetMapping` configuration from there. Non-Entity classes are not scanned.

Comment: @zbig so will we have to add a new table to our DB? if yes, is it possible to have a alternate solution where we don't have to create a new table in the DB?

Comment: It worth mentionning that you can annotate you POJO with `@MappedSuperClass` and then the `@SqlResultSetMapping` will be taken into account. Not the most elegant solution but preferable to me than annotate another random entity.

Comment: This is really not good because you'll end up polluting entities and also people will be wondering how entityManger is failing to map certain native query results to a POJO when they don't know where to find this. The should have allowed it to be picked up without an entity

Answer (score 28):

Short working example:

- DTO POJO class

  ```
  @lombok.Getter
  @lombok.AllArgsConstructor
  public class StatementDto {
      private String authorName;
      private Date createTime;
  }
  ```
- Repository bean:

  ```
  @Repository
  public class StatementNativeRepository {      
      @PersistenceContext private EntityManager em;

      static final String STATEMENT_SQLMAP = "Statement-SQL-Mapping";

      public List<StatementDto> findPipelinedStatements() {
          Query query = em.createNativeQuery(
              "select author_name, create_time from TABLE(SomePipelinedFun('xxx'))",
              STATEMENT_SQLMAP);
          return query.getResultList();
      }

      @SqlResultSetMapping(name= STATEMENT_SQLMAP, classes = {
          @ConstructorResult(targetClass = StatementDto.class,
              columns = {
                  @ColumnResult(name="author_name",type = String.class),
                  @ColumnResult(name="create_time",type = Date.class)
              }
          )
      }) @Entity class SQLMappingCfgEntity{@Id int id;} // <- workaround

  }
  ```

Comment: Great solution, it got me 90% of the way there but I kept getting errors about table validation (table not found).  To fix this I added the annotation to SQLMappingCfgEntity "@Table(name = "DUAL")" and chanced 'int id' to 'String dummy'.  Of course this is an Oracle specific fix, but I like that it's not dependent on a specific table which would be an alternate option.

Comment: The thing I didn't catch at first was that SQLMappingCfgEntity is a different class from StatementDto. SqlResultSetMapping doesn't have to annotate the class you are trying to construct. It has to annotate an Entity class, but you can throw it on ANY Entity class.

Comment: Good solution, but this would be so much nicer if you could put the `@SqlResultSetMapping` annotation on the class instead of having to create a new entity object that not really used.

Comment: This example still gives me the error "Unknown SqlResultSetMapping"

Comment: Thanks, I'm looking for this workaround for 5 hours

Answer (score 10):

### Domain Model

Let's consider we have the following `post` and `post_comment` tables in our database:

[image: JPA SqlResultSetMapping post and post_comment tables]

### JPA `SqlResultSetMapping`

The `SqlResultSetMapping` JPA annotation looks as follows:

```
@Repeatable(SqlResultSetMappings.class)
@Target({TYPE}) 
@Retention(RUNTIME)
public @interface SqlResultSetMapping { 

    String name(); 

    EntityResult[] entities() default {};

    ConstructorResult[] classes() default {};

    ColumnResult[] columns() default {};
}
```

The `SqlResultSetMapping`  annotation is repeatable and is applied at the entity class level. Apart from taking a unique name, which is used by Hibernate to register the mapping, there are three mapping options:

- `EntityResult`
- `ConstructorResult`
- `ColumnResult`

Next, we are going to see how al these three mapping options work, as well as the use cases where you will need to use them.

### JPA SqlResultSetMapping - EntityResult

The `EntityResult` option allows you to map the JDBC `ResultSet` columns to one or more JPA entities.

Let's assume we want to fetch the first 5 `Post` entities along with all their associated `PostComment` entities that match a given `title` pattern.

As I explained in [this article](https://vladmihalcea.com/query-pagination-jpa-hibernate/), we can use the `DENSE_RANK` [SQL Window Function](https://vladmihalcea.com/why-you-should-definitely-learn-sql-window-functions/) to know how to filter the `post` and `post_comment` joined records, as illustrated by the following SQL query:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT
    *,
    DENSE_RANK() OVER (
    ORDER BY
      "p.created_on",
      "p.id"
    ) rank
  FROM (
    SELECT
      p.id AS "p.id", p.created_on AS "p.created_on",
      p.title AS "p.title", pc.post_id AS "pc.post_id",
      pc.id as "pc.id", pc.created_on AS "pc.created_on",
      pc.review AS "pc.review"
    FROM post p
    LEFT JOIN post_comment pc ON p.id = pc.post_id
    WHERE p.title LIKE :titlePattern
    ORDER BY p.created_on
  ) p_pc
) p_pc_r
WHERE p_pc_r.rank <= :rank
```

However, we don't want to return a list of scalar column values. We want to return JPA entities from this query, so we need to configure the `entities` attribute of the `@SqlResultSetMapping` annotation, like this:

```
@NamedNativeQuery(
    name = "PostWithCommentByRank",
    query = """
        SELECT *
        FROM (
          SELECT
            *,
            DENSE_RANK() OVER (
            ORDER BY
              "p.created_on",
              "p.id"
            ) rank
          FROM (
            SELECT
              p.id AS "p.id", p.created_on AS "p.created_on",
              p.title AS "p.title", pc.post_id AS "pc.post_id",
              pc.id as "pc.id", pc.created_on AS "pc.created_on",
              pc.review AS "pc.review"
            FROM post p
            LEFT JOIN post_comment pc ON p.id = pc.post_id
            WHERE p.title LIKE :titlePattern
            ORDER BY p.created_on
          ) p_pc
        ) p_pc_r
        WHERE p_pc_r.rank <= :rank
        """,
    resultSetMapping = "PostWithCommentByRankMapping"
)
@SqlResultSetMapping(
    name = "PostWithCommentByRankMapping",
    entities = {
        @EntityResult(
            entityClass = Post.class,
            fields = {
                @FieldResult(name = "id", column = "p.id"),
                @FieldResult(name = "createdOn", column = "p.created_on"),
                @FieldResult(name = "title", column = "p.title"),
            }
        ),
        @EntityResult(
            entityClass = PostComment.class,
            fields = {
                @FieldResult(name = "id", column = "pc.id"),
                @FieldResult(name = "createdOn", column = "pc.created_on"),
                @FieldResult(name = "review", column = "pc.review"),
                @FieldResult(name = "post", column = "pc.post_id"),
            }
        )
    }
)
```

With the `SqlResultSetMapping` in place, we can fetch the `Post` and `PostComment` entities like this:

```
List<Object[]> postAndCommentList = entityManager
    .createNamedQuery("PostWithCommentByRank")
    .setParameter("titlePattern", "High-Performance Java Persistence %")
    .setParameter("rank", POST_RESULT_COUNT)
    .getResultList();
```

And, we can validate that the entities are properly fetched:

```
assertEquals(
    POST_RESULT_COUNT * COMMENT_COUNT, 
    postAndCommentList.size()
);

for (int i = 0; i < COMMENT_COUNT; i++) {
    Post post = (Post) postAndCommentList.get(i)[0];
    PostComment comment = (PostComment) postAndCommentList.get(i)[1];

    assertTrue(entityManager.contains(post));
    assertTrue(entityManager.contains(comment));

    assertEquals(
        "High-Performance Java Persistence - Chapter 1",
        post.getTitle()
    );

    assertEquals(
        String.format(
            "Comment nr. %d - A must read!",
            i + 1
        ),
        comment.getReview()
    );
}
```

> The `@EntityResult` is also useful when fetching JPA entities via SQL stored procedures. Check out [this article](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-call-oracle-stored-procedures-and-functions-from-hibernate/) for more details.

### JPA SqlResultSetMapping - ConstructorResult

Let's assume we want to execute an aggregation query that counts the number of `post_coment` records for each `post` and returns the `post` `title` for reporting purposes. We can use the following SQL query to achieve this goal:

```
SELECT
  p.id AS "p.id",
  p.title AS "p.title",
  COUNT(pc.*) AS "comment_count"
FROM post_comment pc
LEFT JOIN post p ON p.id = pc.post_id
GROUP BY p.id, p.title
ORDER BY p.id
```

We also want to encapsulate the post title and the comment count in the following DTO:

```
public class PostTitleWithCommentCount {

    private final String postTitle;
    
    private final int commentCount;

    public PostTitleWithCommentCount(
            String postTitle,
            int commentCount) {
        this.postTitle = postTitle;
        this.commentCount = commentCount;
    }

    public String getPostTitle() {
        return postTitle;
    }

    public int getCommentCount() {
        return commentCount;
    }
}
```

To map the result set of the above SQL query to the `PostTitleWithCommentCount` DTO, we can use the `classes` attribute of the `@SqlResultSetMapping` annotation, like this:

```
@NamedNativeQuery(
    name = "PostTitleWithCommentCount",
    query = """
        SELECT
          p.id AS "p.id",
          p.title AS "p.title",
          COUNT(pc.*) AS "comment_count"
        FROM post_comment pc
        LEFT JOIN post p ON p.id = pc.post_id
        GROUP BY p.id, p.title
        ORDER BY p.id
        """,
    resultSetMapping = "PostTitleWithCommentCountMapping"
)
@SqlResultSetMapping(
    name = "PostTitleWithCommentCountMapping",
    classes = {
        @ConstructorResult(
            columns = {
                @ColumnResult(name = "p.title"),
                @ColumnResult(name = "comment_count", type = int.class)
            },
            targetClass = PostTitleWithCommentCount.class
        )
    }
)
```

The `ConstructorResult` annotation allows us to instruct Hibernate what DTO class to use as well as which constructor to be called when instantiating the DTO objects.

Note that we used the `type` attribute of the `@ColumnResult` annotation to specify that the `comment_count` should be cast to a Java `int`. This is needed since some JDBC drivers use either `Long` or `BigInteger` for the SQL aggregation function results.

This is how you can call the `PostTitleWithCommentCount` named native query using JPA:

```
List<PostTitleWithCommentCount> postTitleAndCommentCountList = entityManager
    .createNamedQuery("PostTitleWithCommentCount")
    .setMaxResults(POST_RESULT_COUNT)
    .getResultList();
```

And, we can see that the returned `PostTitleWithCommentCount` DTOs have been fetched properly:

assertEquals(POST_RESULT_COUNT, postTitleAndCommentCountList.size());

```
for (int i = 0; i < POST_RESULT_COUNT; i++) {
    PostTitleWithCommentCount postTitleWithCommentCount = 
        postTitleAndCommentCountList.get(i);

    assertEquals(
        String.format(
            "High-Performance Java Persistence - Chapter %d",
            i + 1
        ),
        postTitleWithCommentCount.getPostTitle()
    );

    assertEquals(COMMENT_COUNT, postTitleWithCommentCount.getCommentCount());
}
```

> For more details about the best way to fetch DTO projections with JPA and Hibernate, check out [this article](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-projection-query-to-a-dto-with-jpa-and-hibernate/).

### JPA SqlResultSetMapping - ColumnResult

The previous example showed how we could map the SQL aggregation result set to a DTO. But, what if we want to return the JPA entity for which we are counting the comments?

To achieve this goal we can use the `entities` attribute to define the `Post` entity we are fetching, and the `classes` attribute of the `@SqlResultSetMapping` annotation to map the scalar value, which in our case is the number of associated `post_comment` records:

```
@NamedNativeQuery(
    name = "PostWithCommentCount",
    query = """
        SELECT
          p.id AS "p.id",
          p.title AS "p.title",
          p.created_on AS "p.created_on",
          COUNT(pc.*) AS "comment_count"
        FROM post_comment pc
        LEFT JOIN post p ON p.id = pc.post_id
        GROUP BY p.id, p.title
        ORDER BY p.id
        """,
    resultSetMapping = "PostWithCommentCountMapping"
)
@SqlResultSetMapping(
    name = "PostWithCommentCountMapping",
    entities = @EntityResult(
        entityClass = Post.class,
        fields = {
            @FieldResult(name = "id", column = "p.id"),
            @FieldResult(name = "createdOn", column = "p.created_on"),
            @FieldResult(name = "title", column = "p.title"),
        }
    ),
    columns = @ColumnResult(
        name = "comment_count",
        type = int.class
    )
)
```

When executing the `PostWithCommentCount` named native query:

```
List<Object[]> postWithCommentCountList = entityManager
    .createNamedQuery("PostWithCommentCount")
    .setMaxResults(POST_RESULT_COUNT)
    .getResultList();
```

we will get both the `Post` entity and the `commentCount` scalar column value:

```
assertEquals(POST_RESULT_COUNT, postWithCommentCountList.size());

for (int i = 0; i < POST_RESULT_COUNT; i++) {
    Post post = (Post) postWithCommentCountList.get(i)[0];
    int commentCount = (int) postWithCommentCountList.get(i)[1];

    assertTrue(entityManager.contains(post));

    assertEquals(i + 1, post.getId().intValue());
    assertEquals(
        String.format(
            "High-Performance Java Persistence - Chapter %d",
            i + 1
        ),
        post.getTitle()
    );

    assertEquals(COMMENT_COUNT, commentCount);
}
```

Answer (score 8):

I able to do it this way:

```
Session session = em().unwrap(Session.class);
SQLQuery q = session.createSQLQuery("YOUR SQL HERE");
q.setResultTransformer( Transformers.aliasToBean( MyNotMappedPojoClassHere.class) );
List<MyNotMappedPojoClassHere> postList = q.list();
```

Comment: Result transformer will work, but it is a hibernate-specific solution not JPA.

Comment: also it is depcrecated since hibernate 5.2

Answer (score 6):

The problem with adding `@Entity` to your DTO POJO is that it will create a table in your db that you don't need. Having to add `@Id` and a transient keyword to necessary fields is also a hassle. A simple solution is to move your `@SqlResultSetMapping` to an abstract class.

```
@MappedSuperclass
@SqlResultSetMapping(name="foo",
    classes = {
        @ConstructorResult(
                targetClass = Bar.class,
                columns = {
                    @ColumnResult(name = "barId", type = Long.class),
                    @ColumnResult(name = "barName", type = String.class),
                    @ColumnResult(name = "barTotal", type = Long.class)
                })
    })

public abstract class sqlMappingCode {}
```

Don't forget to add `@MappedSuperclass`. This will ensure Hibernate auto-wires your mapping.

Update: this functionality is broken in Hibernate 5.4.30.Final, Jira ticket created [HHH-14572](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/jira/software/c/projects/HHH/issues/HHH-14572)

Update 2: It looks like this functionality is permanently broken after 5.4.30.Final. New solution, you will need to add an `@Entity` with a table name, then create two classes:

```
public class CustomSchemaFilterProvider implements SchemaFilterProvider {
// implement code, use CustomSchemaFilter below
}
```

then create a singleton custom filter

```
public class CustomSchemaFilter implements SchemaFilter {
// implement code, check for table names you don't want in your schema
}
```

in your JPA Config file set:

```
jpaProp.put(Environment.HBM2DDL_FILTER_PROVIDER, "com.your.package.CustomSchemaFilterProvider");
// OR
hibernate.hbm2ddl.schema_filter_provider=com.your.package.CustomSchemaFilterProvider
```

this will ensure that your new `@Entity` is ignored by hibernate during mapping

tested with hibernate 5.6.9.Final

Answer (score 3):

```
@Entity
@SqlResultSetMapping(name="ConnexionQueryBean",
   entities={
         @EntityResult(entityClass=com.collecteJ.business.bean.ConnexionQueryBean.class, fields={ 
        @FieldResult(name="utilisateurId", column="UTILISATEUR_ID"),
        @FieldResult(name="nom", column="NOM"),
        @FieldResult(name="prenom", column="PRENOM"),
        @FieldResult(name="nomConnexion", column="NOM_CONNEXION"),
        @FieldResult(name="codeAgence", column="CODE_AGENCE"),
        @FieldResult(name="codeBanque", column="CODE_BANQUE"),
        @FieldResult(name="codeDevise", column="CODE_DEVISE"),
        @FieldResult(name="codeCollecteur", column="CODE_COLLECTEUR")})
   })
public class ConnexionQueryBean implements Serializable {

@Id
private long utilisateurId;
private String codeCollecteur;
private String nom;
private String prenom;
private String nomConnexion; 
private String codeAgence;
private String codeBanque;
private String codeDevise;


public ConnexionQueryBean() {
}


public long getUtilisateurId() {
    return utilisateurId;
}

public void setUtilisateurId(long utilisateurId) {
    this.utilisateurId = utilisateurId;
}

public String getCodeCollecteur() {
    return codeCollecteur;
}

public void setCodeCollecteur(String codeCollecteur) {
    this.codeCollecteur = codeCollecteur;
}


public String getNom() {
    return nom;
}

public void setNom(String nom) {
    this.nom = nom;
}

public String getPrenom() {
    return prenom;
}

public void setPrenom(String prenom) {
    this.prenom = prenom;
}

public String getNomConnexion() {
    return nomConnexion;
}

public void setNomConnexion(String nomConnexion) {
    this.nomConnexion = nomConnexion;
}

public String getCodeAgence() {
    return codeAgence;
}

public void setCodeAgence(String codeAgence) {
    this.codeAgence = codeAgence;
}

public String getCodeBanque() {
    return codeBanque;
}

public void setCodeBanque(String codeBanque) {
    this.codeBanque = codeBanque;
}

public String getCodeDevise() {
    return codeDevise;
}

public void setCodeDevise(String codeDevise) {
    this.codeDevise = codeDevise;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "ConnexionQueryBean{" + "utilisateurId=" + utilisateurId + ", codeCollecteur=" + codeCollecteur + ", nom=" + nom + ", prenom=" + prenom + ", nomConnexion=" + nomConnexion + ", codeAgence=" + codeAgence + ", codeBanque=" + codeBanque + ", codeDevise=" + codeDevise + '}';
}
```

This is not really an entity as it does not match any database table. But the `@Entity` and the `@Id` annotations are compulsories for JPA to understand the mapping. If you don't really want to have `@Entity / @Id` in that class, you can remove the  `@SqlResultSetMapping` annotation and put it in any other entity as far as JPA can scan it.

You should also make sure that your `@ComponentScan` content the corresponding package, if you are using a java based spring configuration, you should explicitly declare your entity in the `persistence.xml/orm.xml`  under the `META-INF` directory.

This is the call

```
String connexionQuery = "SELECT u.UTILISATEUR_ID, u.NOM, u.PRENOM, u.NOM_CONNEXION, a.CODE_AGENCE, a.CODE_BANQUE, a.CODE_DEVISE, c.CODE_COLLECTEUR FROM UTILISATEUR u, AGENCE a, COLLECTEUR c "
            + " WHERE (a.CODE_AGENCE = c.CODE_AGENCE AND u.UTILISATEUR_ID = c.UTILISATEUR_ID AND u.NOM_CONNEXION = '"+nomConnextion+"')";

    ConnexionQueryBean ConnexionResults = (ConnexionQueryBean) defaultService.getEntityManager().createNativeQuery(connexionQuery,"ConnexionQueryBean").getSingleResult();
    System.out.println(ConnexionResults.toString());
```

I'm using Spring, JPA 2.1, Hibernate 5 and Oracle, i think this might not be possible with JPA lower version, find more http://www.thoughts-on-java.org/result-set-mapping-complex-mappings/

Comment: be aware that @ComponentScan is spring proprietary and not necessary in a EE container deployed application.

Answer (score 3):

I have a slightly varied answer which is just derived from wildloop's answer.
Here is my answer:

Constants class: Constants.java

```
public class Constants {
    public final String TESTQUERYRESULT_MAPPING_NAME = "TestQueryResultMapping";
}
```

Result Mapping Class: TestQueryResult.java

```
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.EntityResult;
import javax.persistence.FieldResult;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.SqlResultSetMapping;

@Getter
@Setter
@SqlResultSetMapping(
    //name = "TestQueryResultMapping"
    name = Constants.TESTQUERYRESULT_MAPPING_NAME
    ,entities = @EntityResult(
        entityClass = TestQueryResult.class
        ,fields = {
            @FieldResult(name = "rowId", column = "row_id")
            ,@FieldResult(name = "rowName", column = "row_name")
            ,@FieldResult(name = "value", column = "row_value")
        }
    )
)
@Entity
public class TestQueryResult {
    @Id
    private Integer rowId;

    private String rowName;

    private String value;

}
```

Then... somewhere in my Repository Implementation code:

```
public class TestQueryRepository {
    //... some code here to get the entity manager here

    public TestQueryResult getTopMost(Integer rowName) {
        //... some code here

        String queryString = "... some query string here" + rowName;
        TestQueryResult testQueryResult = null;

        //this.entityManager.createNativeQuery(queryString ,"TestQueryResultMapping").getResultList();
        List<TestQueryResult> results = this.entityManager.createNativeQuery(queryString ,Constants.TESTQUERYRESULT_MAPPING_NAME).getResultList();
        if (results != null && !results.isEmpty()) {
            testQueryResult = results.get(0);
        }

        return testQueryResult;
    }

}
```

... then violah! I got some results :D!

Cheers,
Artanis Zeratul

Answer (score 1):

QLRM could be a alternative: http://simasch.github.io/qlrm/

It is not related to a specific JPA implementation and also works with JDBC.

Answer (score 0):

I recently put together a quick Proof of concept which worked quite well for myself and another developer.

A Spring boot endpoint which uses a Native Query and makes use of SqlResultSetMapping, here are the code snippets.

```
import io.swagger.annotations.Api;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.metrics.annotation.Timed;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.util.List;

import static org.springframework.http.MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE;

@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/rest/yum-query", produces = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@Api(tags = {"notification"})
@Timed(extraTags = {"controller", "YumController"})
public class YumController {

    private final YumService yumService;

    @Autowired
    public YumController(YumService yumService) {
        this.yumService = yumService;
    }

    @GetMapping(produces = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public List<ApprovedApplicationsDTO> findApprovedApplications() {
        return yumService.findApprovedApplications();
    }

}
```

Add my Service

```
import au.edu.qld.qcaa.sate.serviceaara.domain.repository.YumRepositoryCustom;
import au.edu.qld.qcaa.sate.serviceaara.dto.yum.ApprovedApplicationsDTO;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.List;

@Slf4j
@Service
public class YumService {

    private YumRepositoryCustom yumRepositoryCustom;

    @Autowired
    public YumService(YumRepositoryCustom yumRepositoryCustom) {
        this.yumRepositoryCustom = yumRepositoryCustom;
    }

    public List<ApprovedApplicationsDTO> findApprovedApplications() {
        return yumRepositoryCustom.findApprovedApplicationsNativeQuery();
    }

}
```

Setup a new Query Result Class for the native query to map to

```
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import javax.persistence.ColumnResult;
import javax.persistence.ConstructorResult;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.MappedSuperclass;
import javax.persistence.SqlResultSetMapping;
import java.math.BigInteger;

@MappedSuperclass
@SqlResultSetMapping(name = "ApprovedApplicationQueryResultBean",
        classes = {
                @ConstructorResult(
                        targetClass = ApprovedApplicationQueryResultBean.class,
                        columns = {
                                @ColumnResult(name = "application_id", type = BigInteger.class),
                                @ColumnResult(name = "application_type", type = String.class),
                                @ColumnResult(name = "assessment_identifier", type = String.class),
                                @ColumnResult(name = "aara_code", type = String.class),
                                @ColumnResult(name = "aara_code_child", type = String.class),
                                @ColumnResult(name = "completion_year", type = Integer.class),
                                @ColumnResult(name = "reason", type = String.class),
                                @ColumnResult(name = "code", type = String.class),
                                @ColumnResult(name = "long_description", type = String.class),
                                @ColumnResult(name = "identified_condition", type = String.class),
                                @ColumnResult(name = "other", type = String.class),
                                @ColumnResult(name = "decision_code", type = String.class),
                        }
                )
        })
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
public class ApprovedApplicationQueryResultBean {

    @Id
    private BigInteger applicationId;

    private String applicationType;
    private String assessmentIdentifier;
    private String aaraCode;
    private String aaraCodeChild;
    private Integer completionYear;
    private String reason;
    private String code;
    private String longDescription;
    private String identifiedCondition;
    private String other;
    private String decisionCode;

}
```

Creating a new Repository Interface and Implementation class to invoke the query from

```
import au.edu.qld.qcaa.sate.serviceaara.dto.yum.ApprovedApplicationsDTO;

import java.util.List;

public interface YumRepositoryCustom {

    List<ApprovedApplicationsDTO> findApprovedApplicationsNativeQuery();

}

import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.persistence.Query;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

@Component
@Slf4j
public class YumRepositoryCustomImpl implements YumRepositoryCustom {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    @Override
    public List<ApprovedApplicationsDTO> findApprovedApplicationsNativeQuery() {
        StringBuilder q = new StringBuilder();
        q.append("select distinct a4.application_id, a4.application_type, a3.assessment_identifier, ");
        q.append("a3.aara_code, ad.aara_code_child, a3.completion_year, c.reason, rd.code, rd.long_description, ic.identified_condition, ic.other, ad2.decision_code ");
        q.append("from category c ");
        q.append("left join application a4 on a4.application_id = c.application_id ");
        q.append("left join arrangement a3 on a3.application_id = a4.application_id ");
        q.append("left join arrangement_detail ad on a3.arrangement_id  = ad.arrangement_id ");
        q.append("left join identified_condition ic on ic.category_id = c.category_id ");
        q.append("left join reference_data rd on rd.code = c.reason ");
        q.append("left join arrangement_decision ad2 on ad2.arrangement_id  = a3.arrangement_id ");
        q.append("left JOIN (SELECT max(ad3.arrangement_decision_id) as theid ");
        q.append("FROM arrangement_decision ad3 ");
        q.append("GROUP BY ad3.arrangement_id) b on ad2.arrangement_decision_id = b.theid ");

        q.append("where a4.application_type = ?1 and a3.completion_year = ?2 ");

        q.append("and a4.is_active = true and a3.is_active = true and ic.is_active = true and c.is_active = true ");
        q.append("order by 1 ");

        Query query = em.createNativeQuery(q.toString(), "ApprovedApplicationQueryResultBean");
        query.setParameter(1, ApplicationConstants.APPLICATION_TYPE_AARA);
        query.setParameter(2, Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR));

        List<ApprovedApplicationQueryResultBean> entityResults = query.getResultList();
        return entityResults.stream().map(entity -> {
            return mapToDTO(entity);
        }).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    private ApprovedApplicationsDTO mapToDTO(ApprovedApplicationQueryResultBean entity) {
        return ApprovedApplicationsDTO.builder()
                .applicationId(entity.getApplicationId())
                .applicationType(entity.getApplicationType())
                .aaraCode(entity.getAaraCode())
                .aaraCodeChild(entity.getAaraCodeChild())
                .completionYear(entity.getCompletionYear())
                .reason(entity.getReason())
                .code(entity.getCode())
                .longDescription(entity.getLongDescription())
                .identifiedCondition(entity.getIdentifiedCondition())
                .other(entity.getOther())
                .decisionCode(entity.getDecisionCode())
                .build();
    }

}
```

Add my endpoint response DTO

```
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;

import java.math.BigInteger;

@Data
@Builder
public class ApprovedApplicationsDTO {
    private BigInteger applicationId;
    private String applicationType;
    private String assessmentIdentifier;
    private String aaraCode;
    private String aaraCodeChild;
    private Integer completionYear;
    private String reason;
    private String code;
    private String longDescription;
    private String identifiedCondition;
    private String other;
    private String decisionCode;

}
```

```
Then hit my endpoint via postman or curl or which ever tool you wish to use:
http://localhost:10050/rest/yum-query
```

Answer (score 0):

Use following, no need to maintain sequence of columns to be mapped by using @EntityResult

```
Used in conjunction with the SqlResultSetMapping annotation to map the SELECT clause of a SQL query to an entity result.
```

If this annotation is used, the SQL statement should select all of the columns that are mapped to the entity object. This should include foreign key columns to related entities. The results obtained when insufficient data is available are undefined.
Example:

```
Query q = em.createNativeQuery(
    "SELECT o.id, o.quantity, o.item, i.id, i.name, i.description "+
        "FROM Order o, Item i " +
        "WHERE (o.quantity > 25) AND (o.item = i.id)",
    "OrderItemResults");
@SqlResultSetMapping(name="OrderItemResults",
    entities={
        @EntityResult(entityClass=com.acme.Order.class),
        @EntityResult(entityClass=com.acme.Item.class)
})
```

Answer (score -1):

This solution is independent of JPA implementation. Once you collect result of native query as

```
List<Object[]> = em.createNativeQueryBar(QUERY, "foo").getResultList();
```

and if you need to map each List element to a Person e.g.

```
Class Person { String name; Int age; }
```

where List element[0] is name and element [ 1] is age.

You can convert Object[] to Person using [ObjectMapper](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.5/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html). You need to add @JsonFormat annotation on the class.

```
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.ARRAY) 
Class Person { String name; Int age; }
```

and convert Object[] to Person as

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(Arrays.asList(attributes)).toString();
Person person = mapper.readValue(jsonArray, Person.class);
```

Answer (score -2):

```
@MappedSuperclass
@SqlResultSetMapping(name="foo",
classes = {
    @ConstructorResult(
            targetClass = Bar.class,
            columns = {
                @ColumnResult(name = "barId", type = Long.class),
                @ColumnResult(name = "barName", type = String.class),
                @ColumnResult(name = "barTotal", type = Long.class)
            })
})
```

You can do it like this, but this is not very recommended because it is not very comfortable. You can do it like below.

```
Query query = em.createNativeQueryBar(QUERY);
... set some parameters ...
List<Object[]> result = query.getResultList();
List<Bar> list = result.stream().map(
        objects -> {
            Bar bar = new Bar();
            bar.setBarId(Long.parseLong(objects[0].toString()));
            bar.setBarName(objects[1].toString());
            bar.setBarTotal(Long.parseLong(objects[2].toString()));
            ...
            
            return bar;
        }
).collect(Collectors.toList());
```