# Spring : JPA to convert native SQL to non entity pojo

Tags: java, spring, jpa, pojo

I have native SQL which returns the collection of objects and i would like to get the results as collection of objects(a pojo class which is non entity)

```
is it possible to get the results from native SQL as collection of non entity?

I am using spring jpa 1.10
```

Comment: Are you looking for [SqlResultSetMapping](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/SqlResultSetMapping.html)? It works only with JPA 2.1 versions or above.

Comment: and if not using JPA 2.1 then it depends on your JPA provider, but you dont say which one you use. I know that DataNucleus supports such transformation pre-JPA 2.1

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to mapping non-entity classes in JPA 1.

Since JPA 2.1, you can use [ConstructorResult](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/ConstructorResult.html), Used in conjunction with the `SqlResultSetMapping` annotation to map the SELECT clause of a SQL query to a constructor.

Here is the example

```
Query q = em.createNativeQuery(
      "SELECT c.id, c.name, COUNT(o) as orderCount, AVG(o.price) AS avgOrder " +
      "FROM Customer c, Orders o " +
      "WHERE o.cid = c.id " +
      "GROUP BY c.id, c.name",
      "CustomerDetailsResult");

   @SqlResultSetMapping(
       name="CustomerDetailsResult",
       classes={
          @ConstructorResult(
               targetClass=com.acme.CustomerDetails.class,
                 columns={
                    @ColumnResult(name="id"),
                    @ColumnResult(name="name"),
                    @ColumnResult(name="orderCount"),
                    @ColumnResult(name="avgOrder", type=Double.class)
                    }
          )
       }
      )
```

Comment: Thanks is it possible to have namedquery and map the pojo?

Comment: @SAR http://www.concretepage.com/hibernate/native_query_hibernate_annotation might help you

Comment: @harshavmb thanks but what i have is NON ENTITY, and that is where the issue comes up :)

Comment: @SAR Actually you just need to configure the query name. and for NamedQuery, there is a resultClass parameter( as remember, you can have a try ).

Comment: @LipingHuang No, it did not work, i have tried that too. :), the issues is that it is not entity, that is why all these issues came up

Comment: @LipingHuang sure Thank you so much

Comment: @SAR and my interesting is you add the namedquery in a non-entity?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146132/discussion-between-sar-and-liping-huang).

Answer (score 0):

[Mapping NativeQuery results into a POJO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57977188/1640220) - this is JPA independent solution using @JsonFormat and [ObjectMapper](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.5/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html), detailed with code sample to what @darshan-patel already mentioned.