# @NamedNativeQuery - How can I bind it to a repository method?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am using `Spring` + `Hibernate` and I have a particular case where I need to obtain (a list of) non-`Entity` objects as a result of the query.

I decided to use `@ConstructorResult` in `@SqlResultSetMapping` and refer to this mapping in `@NamedNativeQuery`, as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29082749/spring-data-jpa-map-the-result-to-non-entity-pojo) and [here](https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/result-set-mapping-constructor-result-mappings/).

However, in all examples using named native queries, they obtain `EntityManager` instance via `@PersistenceContext` and call `createNativeQuery` on it, providing the `name` of `@NamedNativeQuery` as parameter to that call, as seen in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36109273/7491770) answer.

How can I map a method declared in a repository `interface` to a particular `@NamedNativeQuery`? My attempt was to use `EntityName.MethodNameInRepository` or `MethodNameInRepository` as the `name` of `@NamedNativeQuery`, but no luck.

Here is my simplified code:

```
@Entity(name = "AdDailyData")
@SqlResultSetMapping(
        name="RevenueByAppAndDayMapping",
        classes=@ConstructorResult(
                targetClass=RevenueByAppAndDay.class,
                columns={@ColumnResult(name="country_code"),
                        @ColumnResult(name="revenue", type=Double.class),
                        @ColumnResult(name="currency")}))
@NamedNativeQuery(
        name="AdDailyData.aggregateRevenue",
        query="SELECT country_code, sum(earnings) as revenue, currency "
                + "FROM ad_daily_data, pseudo_app, app "
                + "WHERE ad_daily_data.pseudo_app_id=pseudo_app.id AND pseudo_app.app_id=app.id AND app.id=:appId and ad_daily_data.day = :day "
                + "GROUP BY country_code, currency "
                + "ORDER BY country_code ASC",
        resultSetMapping="RevenueByAppAndDayMapping")
public class AdDailyDataEntity {

    // fields, getters, setters etc.

    public static interface Repository extends JpaRepository<AdDailyDataEntity, Long> {

        public List<RevenueByAppAndDay> aggregateRevenue(@Param("appId") long appId, @Param("day") LocalDate day);

    }

}
```

Here is my non-`Entity` class.

```
public class RevenueByAppAndDay {

    private String countryCode;
    private Double earnings;
    private String currency;

    public RevenueByAppAndDay(String countryCode, Double earnings, String currency) {
        this.countryCode = countryCode;
        this.earnings = earnings;
        this.currency = currency;
    }

    public String getCountryCode() {
        return countryCode;
    }

    public Double getEarnings() {
        return earnings;
    }

    public String getCurrency() {
        return currency;
    }

}
```

Any kind of help is highly appreciated.

**EDIT:**
The end of the stack trace is as follows:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property aggregateRevenue found for type AdDailyDataEntity!
```

Comment: Can you add the stacktrace that you are receiving?

Comment: @GrantLay added the exception.

Comment: How would aggregateRevenue be called from a service? I've tried autowiring AdDailyDataEntity and calling adDailyDataEntity.aggregateRevenue but I get an error that the method is not defined.

Comment: @MichoRizo you should autowire repository, not entity.

Comment: Sorry, i meant how do I  call from repository. Trying to extend crudrepository with method List<RevenueByAppAndDay> aggregateRevenue(...) but get no property found. I'll start up another question

Comment: @ram. Thank you for your detailed question. It helped me to learn and write JPA named query with ease.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The `name` value on the `@NamedNativeQuery` needs to be set to `"AdDailyDataEntity.aggregateRevenue"`.  The first part (before the dot) needs to match the entity class name.

Comment: This is not working for me _"Errors in named queries: CashFlowDetail.findCashFlowDetails"_

Comment: This works for real entities only, where the at.NamedNativeQuery are within the Entity class. The question included the use of @SqlResultSetMapping.

Answer (score -1):

Although the answer is correct, for someone to arrived here for similar cuestions this works for me without used @NamedNativeQuery:

```
public class Example {

private Long someProperty;
// getters and setters
}
```

To call a query or stored procedure and populate my object:

```
@Repository
public interface ExampleRepository extends 
JpaRepository<Example,Long> {

/**
 * Search Example by someProperty
 *
 * @param property
 * @return
 */
@Query( nativeQuery = true, value = "SELECT * FROM public.my_stored_procedure(:property)")
List<Example> findByProperty(@Param("property") Long property);

}
```

I know this is another approach and the code is decoupled, but we get the same result.

I hope that can be useful for someone.
Regards.

Comment: This approach won't work unless `Example` is a managed entity which it's not (according to the question).

Comment: Hi, io-german, I've mentioned this approach because I've used it. My entity is not managed. In the beginning, I thought using a SQL View, but my requirement didn't let me, then I've created a store procedure and then populate a DTO object. 

Have you had the opportunity to try it?
With much respect, I have put that it is an alternative approach, I have mentioned that there is already a correct answer.

Regards.

Comment: @io-german, could you prove your point? My intention is for learning, may make a mistake.

Comment: sorry for the late response. I have found that for some reason skipped the stored procedure creation and tried to call a regular query via NamedNativeQuery API. I'll remove both the downvote and both my comments. Sorry for confusion