# @NamedNativeQuery with @SqlResultSetMapping for non-entity

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa, named-query, sqlresultsetmapping

I have been using this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44871757/namednativequery-how-can-i-bind-it-to-a-repository-method?noredirect=1#comment85443716_44871757) as an example.
I have a complex join query (simplified here). It returns a subset of values from two tables (and a derived column using CASE). I don't think I need to use an entity annotation because the object returned from my result set is not an actual table in my schema.

My non-entity object that I want to hold results from my join query:

```
@SqlResultSetMapping(
           name="myMapping",
           classes={
              @ConstructorResult(
                   targetClass=CarLimitDelta.class,
                     columns={
                        @ColumnResult(name="caseCol"),
                        @ColumnResult(name="colA"),
                        @ColumnResult(name="colB"),
                        }
              )
           }
)
@NamedNativeQuery(name="CarLimitDelta.getCarLimitDelta", 
        resultSetMapping="myMapping", 
        query="SELECT CASE "+ 
           "WHEN t.foo IS NULL THEN 'INS' "+
           "WHEN s.foo IS NULL THEN 'DEL' "+
           "ELSE 'UPD' "+
        "END caseCol "+
     ", T.bar colA "+
     ", S.bar ColB "+
     "FROM tableA S "+
     "FULL JOIN TableB ON S.bar= T.bar")

public class CarLimitDelta {
        private String caseCol;
        private String colA;
        private String colB;


    //getters/setters/etc
    }
```

My repo:

```
@Repository
public interface CarLimitRepository extends CrudRepository<CarLimitDelta, String> {
    List<CarLimitDelta> getCarLimitDelta();
}
```

my Service:

```
@Service
public class CarLimitService {

    @Autowired
    CarLimitRepository carLimitRepository ;

    public void deleteAll() {
        carLimitRepository.deleteAll();
    }

    public List<CarLimitDelta> getCarLimitDelta() {
        return carLimitRepository.getCarLimitDelta();
    }


}
```

I'm not sure how to get my repo to see my new CarLimitDelta.getCarLimitDelta native query method defined in my NamedNativeQuery. I get the following error:

> Invalid derived query! No property getCarLimitDelta found for type
>   CarLimitDelta!

Comment: I ended up getting around this by just creating a view in my db and using the standard entity/repo/service structure instead of calling a native query. I will look at the native query solution later.

Answer (score 16):

The `@SqlResultSetMapping` and `@NamedNativeQuery` annotations need to be on an `@Entity`, not on the non-entity POJO.

If the entity is `Foo`, then add the annotations as follows:

```
@SqlResultSetMapping(
           name="myMapping",
           classes={
              @ConstructorResult(
                   targetClass=CarLimitDelta.class,
                     columns={
                        @ColumnResult(name="caseCol"),
                        @ColumnResult(name="colA"),
                        @ColumnResult(name="colB"),
                        }
              )
           }
)
@NamedNativeQuery(name="Foo.getCarLimitDelta", 
        resultSetMapping="myMapping", 
        query="...")
@Entity
public class Foo {
  ...
}
```

Note that the `@NamedNativeQuery` name is prefixed with the entity name, e.g. `Foo.getCarLimitDelta`.

Then add the method to the Foo repository:

```
@Repository
public interface FooRepository extends CrudRepository<Foo, String> {
    List<CarLimitDelta> getCarLimitDelta();
}
```

Note that the method name, `getCarLimitDelta`, matches the `@NamedNativeQuery` name, minus the prefix.

Comment: It is a bit silly: You want to create a query that puts data into a DTO, not an Entity, and you get to define it in conjunction with an entity class. To express that clearly, I usually define the SqlResultSetMapping on a "dummy class": ```class DummyEntity() { @Id var id: Long? = null }``` (Kotlin), especially when I generate native SQL with JOOQ.