# java.sql.SQLException: Column not found for non-entity object

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I have 2 Entities: Order DTO and TopUperShiftDTO. I have a query where I sum values from OrderDTO (and TopUperShiftDTO through JOIN) and I want to use that summed values as arguments in the constructor for my non-entity TotalIngamePerDayDTO.

I was following this suggestion from "codemonkey" from this thread: [@NamedNativeQuery with @SqlResultSetMapping for non-entity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49225739/namednativequery-with-sqlresultsetmapping-for-non-entity)

My Entity OrderDTO (I didn't wrote here getters and setters, but they exist):

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "client_order")
    @SqlResultSetMapping(name = "perDay", classes = {
            @ConstructorResult(targetClass = TotalIngamePerDayDTO.class,
                    columns = {@ColumnResult(name = "date"), @ColumnResult(name = "thirdShift"),
                            @ColumnResult(name = "firstShift"), @ColumnResult(name = "secondShift"),
                            @ColumnResult(name = "china"), @ColumnResult(name = "spent"),
                            @ColumnResult(name = "totalOrders"), @ColumnResult(name = "totalPoints"),
                            @ColumnResult(name = "totalIngame")})
    })
    @NamedNativeQuery(name = "OrderDTO.getTotalIngamePerDayDTO", resultSetMapping = "perDay", 
    query = "SELECT date,"
            + " COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN (top_uper_shift.shift_start >= :thirdShiftStart) THEN ingame ELSE 0 END), 0), "
            + " COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN (top_uper_shift.shift_start >= :firstShiftStart) THEN ingame ELSE 0 END), 0), "
            + " COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN (top_uper_shift.shift_start >= :secondShiftStart) THEN ingame ELSE 0 END), 0), "
            + " COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN (platform = 'China') THEN ingame ELSE 0 END), 0), "
            + " COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN (platform != 'China') THEN ingame ELSE 0 END), 0), "
            + " COUNT(order_id), "
            + " COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN(platform = 'Google Points') THEN ingame ELSE 0 END), 0),"
            + " COALESCE(SUM(ingame), 0)"
            + " FROM client_order INNER JOIN top_uper_shift ON client_order.top_uper_shift_shift_id = top_uper_shift.shift_id "
            + " WHERE top_uper_shift.shift_start BETWEEN :thirdShiftStart AND :secondShiftStart ")
    public class OrderDTO
    {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        @Column(name = "order_id")
        private int orderId;
        @Column(name = "date")
        private LocalDate date;
        @Column(name = "time")
        private LocalTime time;
        @Column(name = "order_type")
        private String orderType;
        @Column(name = "platform")
        private String platform;
        @Column(name = "payment")
        private String payment;
        @Column(name = "ingame")
        private BigDecimal ingame;
        @Column(name = "money")
        private BigDecimal money;
        @Column(name = "currency")
        private String currency;
        @Column(name = "amazon_coins")
        private int amazonCoins;
        @Column(name = "deposit")
        private BigDecimal deposit;
        @Column(name = "notes")
        private String notes;
        @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        private ClientDTO client;
        @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        private TopUperShiftDTO topUperShift;
        @ManyToOne
        private SellerDTO seller;
        
        public OrderDTO()
        {
            this.ingame = BigDecimal.ZERO;
            this.money = BigDecimal.ZERO;
            this.amazonCoins = 0;
            this.deposit = BigDecimal.ZERO;
        }
        
    }
```

TotalIngamePerDayDTO:

```
package com.KingDogeTeam.DTO;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.time.LocalDate;



public class TotalIngamePerDayDTO
{
    private LocalDate date;
    private BigDecimal thirdShift;
    private BigDecimal firstShift;
    private BigDecimal secondShift;
    private BigDecimal china;
    private BigDecimal spent;
    private int totalOrders;
    private BigDecimal totalPoints;
    private BigDecimal totalIngame;
    
    public TotalIngamePerDayDTO(){}

    public TotalIngamePerDayDTO(LocalDate date, BigDecimal thirdShift, BigDecimal firstShift, BigDecimal secondShift, BigDecimal china, 
            BigDecimal spent, int totalOrders,  BigDecimal totalPoints, BigDecimal totalIngame)
    {
        this.date = date;
        this.thirdShift = thirdShift;
        this.firstShift = firstShift;
        this.secondShift = secondShift;
        this.china = china;
        this.spent = spent;
        this.totalOrders = totalOrders;
        this.totalPoints = totalPoints;
        this.totalIngame = totalIngame;
    }
}
```

IOrderRepository:

```
@Repository
public interface IOrderRepository extends JpaRepository<OrderDTO, Integer>
{
    TotalIngamePerDayDTO getTotalIngamePerDayDTO(LocalDateTime thirdShiftStart, LocalDateTime firstShiftStart, LocalDateTime secondShiftStart);
}
```

I've got java.sql.SQLException: Column 'thirdShift' not found.
Full trace stack:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Column 'thirdShift' not found.
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:89) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:63) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.result.ResultSetImpl.findColumn(ResultSetImpl.java:575) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.23.jar:8.0.23]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyResultSet.findColumn(HikariProxyResultSet.java) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.JdbcResultMetadata.resolveColumnPosition(JdbcResultMetadata.java:51) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar:5.4.30.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.ScalarResultColumnProcessor.performDiscovery(ScalarResultColumnProcessor.java:42) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar:5.4.30.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.ConstructorResultColumnProcessor.performDiscovery(ConstructorResultColumnProcessor.java:40) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar:5.4.30.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.autoDiscoverTypes(CustomLoader.java:494) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar:5.4.30.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.preprocessResultSet(Loader.java:2349) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar:5.4.30.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2305) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar:5.4.30.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:2056) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar:5.4.30.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:2018) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar:5.4.30.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:948) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar:5.4.30.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:349) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar:5.4.30.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2849) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar:5.4.30.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2831) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar:5.4.30.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2663) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar:5.4.30.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2658) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar:5.4.30.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.list(CustomLoader.java:338) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar:5.4.30.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.listCustomQuery(SessionImpl.java:2141) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar:5.4.30.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.list(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:1172) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar:5.4.30.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.NativeQueryImpl.doList(NativeQueryImpl.java:176) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar:5.4.30.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1593) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar:5.4.30.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.getSingleResult(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1641) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.30.Final.jar:5.4.30.Final]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$SingleEntityExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:196) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.5.4.jar:2.5.4]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:88) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.5.4.jar:2.5.4]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:155) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.5.4.jar:2.5.4]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:143) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.5.4.jar:2.5.4]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:137) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.8.jar:2.4.8]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:121) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.8.jar:2.4.8]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:152) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.8.jar:2.4.8]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:131) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.8.jar:2.4.8]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:80) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.8.jar:2.4.8]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123) ~[spring-tx-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388) ~[spring-tx-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-tx-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137) ~[spring-tx-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:145) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.5.4.jar:2.5.4]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97) ~[spring-aop-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215) ~[spring-aop-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at jdk.proxy5/jdk.proxy5.$Proxy176.getTotalIngamePerDayDTO(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.KingDogeTeam.Services.TotalIngamePerDayService.getTotalIngamePerDay(TotalIngamePerDayService.java:98) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.KingDogeTeam.Controllers.InGameDashboardController.ingamePerDayDashboard(InGameDashboardController.java:218) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:197) ~[spring-web-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:141) ~[spring-web-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:894) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1060) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:962) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:626) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:327) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.6.jar:5.4.6]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:115) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.6.jar:5.4.6]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:81) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.6.jar:5.4.6]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.6.jar:5.4.6]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.6.jar:5.4.6]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.6.jar:5.4.6]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.6.jar:5.4.6]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:126) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.6.jar:5.4.6]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:81) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.6.jar:5.4.6]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.6.jar:5.4.6]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:105) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.6.jar:5.4.6]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.6.jar:5.4.6]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:149) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.6.jar:5.4.6]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.6.jar:5.4.6]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.6.jar:5.4.6]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.6.jar:5.4.6]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:218) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.6.jar:5.4.6]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:212) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.6.jar:5.4.6]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.6.jar:5.4.6]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:103) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.6.jar:5.4.6]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:89) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.6.jar:5.4.6]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.6.jar:5.4.6]
    at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:117) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.6.jar:5.4.6]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.6.jar:5.4.6]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.6.jar:5.4.6]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.6.jar:5.4.6]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.6.jar:5.4.6]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:110) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.6.jar:5.4.6]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:80) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.6.jar:5.4.6]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.6.jar:5.4.6]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:55) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.6.jar:5.4.6]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.6.jar:5.4.6]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:211) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.6.jar:5.4.6]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:183) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.6.jar:5.4.6]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358) ~[spring-web-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271) ~[spring-web-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter.doFilterInternal(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:141) ~[spring-session-core-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.springframework.session.web.http.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:82) ~[spring-session-core-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1707) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.45.jar:9.0.45]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831) ~[na:na]
```

I've also tried before with constructor with hql query, but I got the same error:

```
//      String hql = " SELECT new com.KingDogeTeam.DTO.TotalIngamePerDayDTO(:date, "
//              + " CAST(COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN (o.topUperShift.shiftStart >= :thirdShiftStart) THEN o.ingame ELSE 0 END), 0) AS double), "
//              + " CAST(COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN (o.topUperShift.shiftStart >= :firstShiftStart) THEN o.ingame ELSE 0 END), 0) AS double),"
//              + " CAST(COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN (o.topUperShift.shiftStart >= :secondShiftStart) THEN o.ingame ELSE 0 END), 0) AS double), "
//              + " CAST(COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN o.platform = 'China' THEN o.ingame ELSE 0 END), 0) AS double), "
//              + " CAST(COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN o.platform != 'China' THEN o.ingame ELSE 0 END), 0) AS double), "
//              + " CAST(COUNT(o.orderId) AS int), "
//              + " CAST(COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN o.platform = 'Google Points' THEN o.ingame ELSE 0 END), 0) AS int),"
//              + " CAST(COALESCE(SUM(o.ingame), 0) AS double)) "
//              + " FROM OrderDTO o WHERE (o.topUperShift.shiftStart BETWEEN :thirdShiftStart AND :secondShiftStart) ";
```

Comment: I don't believe that you get the same error with the second query because there is no thirdShift selected.