# Mapping an SQL native query to a POJO class

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.1, sqlresultsetmapping

I tried to map a native SQL query to a POJO class using `@ConstructorResult` of `@SqlResultSetMapping` as following :

```
@SqlResultSetMapping(
        name = "AnomalieMapping",
        classes = @ConstructorResult(
                targetClass = Anomalie.class,
                columns = {
                        @ColumnResult(name = "anomalieElement", type = String.class),
                        @ColumnResult(name = "anomalieType", type = String.class),
                        @ColumnResult(name = "libelle", type = String.class) }))
public class Anomalie {

    private ElementAnomalieEnum anomalieElement;
    private TypeAnomalieEnum anomalieType;
    private String libelle;

    public Anomalie() {
        super();
    }

    public Anomalie(final String libelle, final String anomalieElement, final String anomalieType) {
        super();
        this.libelle = libelle;
        this.anomalieElement = ElementAnomalieEnum.valueOf(StringUtils.stripAccents(anomalieElement.toUpperCase()));
        this.anomalieType = TypeAnomalieEnum.valueOf(StringUtils.stripAccents(anomalieType.substring(5).toUpperCase()));

    }
//Getters and Setters
}
```

And then to use the declared result-set mapping in creating the native query, I reference it by its name:

```
Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery(sqlQuery, "AnomalieMapping");
return query.getResultList();
```

But this didn't work for me I get the following error :

> org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown SqlResultSetMapping
>   [AnomalieMapping]

This is what my SQL query is generating when I execute it in the SGBD:

[image]

Comment: and is this annotation in a class that is processed by your JPA provider?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25188939/mapping-nativequery-results-into-a-pojo

Comment: @DN1 how can I check that ?

Comment: Only you know what class it is specified on, or whether that class is an entity, or if it is specified in persistence.xml

Comment: @hasnae the solution for that question was to add the `Entity` annotation which didn't work in my case.

Comment: @DN1 The class `Anomalie` is not an entity it's a POJO class, that's why I don't need to declare it inside `persistence.xml` neither declaring the `Entity` annotation.

Comment: and so your JPA provider has no idea what it is. So it is ignored. So you get an exception. So it wont work until you change that ...

Comment: @DN1 as I know in JPA 2.1 the `ConstructorResult` won't need the declaration of my POJO class as an entity.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I solved my problem:

Instead of declaring `@SqlResultSetMapping` annotation I declared it in `orm.xml` file as following:

```
<sql-result-set-mapping name="AnomalieMapping">
        <constructor-result target-class="xxx.Anomalie">
            <column name="libelle"/>
            <column name="anomalieElement"/>
            <column name="anomalieType"/>
        </constructor-result>
    </sql-result-set-mapping>
```

And then in my DAO I get the result as following:

```
Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery(sqlQuery, "AnomalieMapping");
return query.getResultList();
```