# Hibernate exception w.r.t mapping after migrating to 3.0.1

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Error facing..

```
2023-05-18T19:10:14.988+05:30 ERROR 18796 --- [nio-8082-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet]      : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [/cascca/bapi] threw exception [Request processing failed: jakarta.persistence.PersistenceException: Converting `org.hibernate.HibernateException` to JPA `PersistenceException` : Could not resolve specified result-set mapping name : herculesforecast] with root cause

org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not resolve specified result-set mapping name : herculesforecast
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createNativeQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:801) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.4.Final.jar:6.1.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createNativeQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:127) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.4.Final.jar:6.1.4.Final]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:360) ~[spring-orm-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy152.createNativeQuery(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:307) ~[spring-orm-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy152.createNativeQuery(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.cargill.api.casc.service.jarvis.repository.JarvisRepo.getQueryResponse(JarvisRepo.java:66) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.cargill.api.casc.service.jarvis.service.JarvisService.getResponse(JarvisService.java:94) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343) ~[spring-aop-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:698) ~[spring-aop-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at com.cargill.api.casc.service.jarvis.service.JarvisService$$SpringCGLIB$$0.getResponse(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.cargill.api.casc.service.jarvis.controller.MSController.getHerculesForecast(MSController.java:389) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:207) ~[spring-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:152) ~[spring-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:884) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1080) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:973) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1010) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:902) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:564) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:6.0]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:884) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:658) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:6.0]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:205) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.ServerHttpObservationFilter.doFilterInternal(ServerHttpObservationFilter.java:109) ~[spring-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:482) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:341) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:390) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:894) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
```

Creating the native query:

```
package com.cargill.api.casc.service.jarvis.repository;

import com.cargill.api.casc.service.jarvis.util.JarvisUtil;
import jakarta.persistence.EntityManager;
import jakarta.persistence.Query;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

//@Primary
@Component("jarvisrepo")
public class JarvisRepo {

    @Autowired
    private JarvisUtil jarvisUtil;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier(value = "mainEntityManager")
    private EntityManager em;

    @Value("#{${jarvis.whereClause.map}}")
    Map<String, String> whereClauseMap;

    @Value("#{${jarvis.table.map}}")
    Map<String, String> tableMap;

    @Value("#{${jarvis.query.map}}")
    Map<String, String> queryMap;

    @Value("#{${jarvis.orderBy.map}}")
    Map<String, String> orderByMap;

    @Value("#{${jarvis.groupBy.map}}")
    Map<String, String> groupByMap;

    @Value("#{${jarvis.custom.map}}")
    Map<String, String> customMap;

    private String getLimitOffsetQueryString() {
        return " limit :limit offset :offset";
    }

    public <T> List<T> getQueryResponse(Map<String, Object> paramMap, Integer limit, Integer offset, String baseTableName) {

        StringBuilder selectQuery = new StringBuilder();
        Map<String, Object> queryParamMap = new HashMap<>();
        StringBuilder whereQueryString = new StringBuilder();
        selectQuery.append(queryMap.get(baseTableName));
        whereQueryString = jarvisUtil.addWhereCaluse(paramMap, queryParamMap, whereQueryString, whereClauseMap);
        if(customMap.containsKey(baseTableName)) {
            whereQueryString.append(customMap.get(baseTableName));
        }
        if(groupByMap.containsKey(baseTableName)){
            whereQueryString.append(groupByMap.get(baseTableName));
        }
        whereQueryString.append(orderByMap.get(baseTableName)).append(getLimitOffsetQueryString());
        if (whereQueryString.length() > 0) {
            selectQuery.append(" WHERE ");
            selectQuery.append(whereQueryString);
        }
        Query query = em.createNativeQuery(selectQuery.toString(), baseTableName);
        addParamForOffsetLimit(queryParamMap, offset, limit);
        queryParamMap.forEach((key, value) -> {
            query.setParameter(key, value);
        });
        return query.getResultList();
    }

    public List<Object[]> getTableCount(Map<String, Object> paramMap,String table) {
        StringBuilder routeRateCount = new StringBuilder();
        Map<String, Object> queryParamMap = new HashMap<>();
        StringBuilder whereQueryString = new StringBuilder();
        routeRateCount.append("select Count(*)  from ").append(tableMap.get(table));
        whereQueryString = jarvisUtil.addWhereCaluse(paramMap, queryParamMap, whereQueryString, whereClauseMap);
        if (whereQueryString.length() > 0) {
            routeRateCount.append(" WHERE ");
            routeRateCount.append(whereQueryString);
        }
        if(customMap.containsKey(table)) {
            routeRateCount.append(customMap.get(table));
        }
        Query query = em.createNativeQuery(routeRateCount.toString());
        queryParamMap.forEach((key, value) -> {
            query.setParameter(key, value);
        });
        return query.getResultList();
    }


    private Map<String, Object> addParamForOffsetLimit(Map<String, Object> map, Integer offset, Integer limit) {
        map.put("limit", limit);
        map.put("offset", offset);
        return map;
    }


}
```

Annotation class:

```
package com.cargill.api.casc.service.jarvis.model;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import jakarta.persistence.ColumnResult;
import jakarta.persistence.ConstructorResult;
import jakarta.persistence.MappedSuperclass;
import jakarta.persistence.SqlResultSetMapping;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.ToString;


@ToString
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@MappedSuperclass
@SqlResultSetMapping(name = "herculesforecast", classes = {
        @ConstructorResult(targetClass = HerculesForecast.class, columns = {
                @ColumnResult(name = "source_system", type = String.class),
                @ColumnResult(name = "week", type = String.class),
                @ColumnResult(name = "cycle", type = String.class),
                @ColumnResult(name = "terminal", type = String.class),
                @ColumnResult(name = "corridor", type = String.class),
                @ColumnResult(name = "commodity", type = String.class),
                @ColumnResult(name = "forecast_year", type = Integer.class),
                @ColumnResult(name = "forecast_month", type = Integer.class),
                @ColumnResult(name = "first_day_of_month", type = String.class),
                @ColumnResult(name = "is_current_cycle", type = Integer.class),
                @ColumnResult(name = "capacity", type = Double.class),
                @ColumnResult(name = "budget_volume", type = Double.class),
                @ColumnResult(name = "sales_forecast", type = Double.class),
                @ColumnResult(name = "location_shipping_forecast", type = Double.class),
                @ColumnResult(name = "roll_previous_month", type = Double.class),
                @ColumnResult(name = "total_sold", type = Double.class),
                @ColumnResult(name = "total_sold_roll_in", type = Double.class),
                @ColumnResult(name = "shipped_in_month", type = Double.class),
                @ColumnResult(name = "sales_rolled_next_month", type = Double.class),
                @ColumnResult(name = "left_to_ship", type = Double.class),
                @ColumnResult(name = "unsold_allocated_capacity", type = Double.class),
                @ColumnResult(name = "unallocated_capacity", type = Double.class),
                @ColumnResult(name = "unshipped_capacity", type = Double.class),
                @ColumnResult(name = "previous_3_months_forecast", type = Double.class),
                @ColumnResult(name = "forecast_accuracy", type = Double.class),
                @ColumnResult(name = "total_unsold", type = Double.class),
                @ColumnResult(name = "total_projected_shipments", type = Double.class),
                @ColumnResult(name = "initial_inventory", type = Double.class),
                @ColumnResult(name = "total_inbounds", type = Double.class),
                @ColumnResult(name = "last_year_shipped_in_month", type = Double.class),
                @ColumnResult(name = "fiscal_year", type = String.class),

        }) })

public class HerculesForecast {

    @JsonProperty("source_system")
    private String sourceSystem;


    @JsonProperty("week")
    private String week;

    @JsonProperty("cycle")
    private String cycle;

    @JsonProperty("terminal")
    private String terminal;

    @JsonProperty("corridor")
    private String corridor;

    @JsonProperty("commodity")
    private String commodity;

    @JsonProperty("forecast_year")
    private Integer forecastYear;

    @JsonProperty("forecast_month")
    private Integer forecastMonth;

    @JsonProperty("first_day_of_month")
    private String firstDayOfMonth;

    @JsonProperty("is_current_cycle")
    private Integer isCurrentCycle;

    @JsonProperty("capacity")
    private Double capacity;

    @JsonProperty("budget_volume")
    private Double budgetVolume;

    @JsonProperty("sales_forecast")
    private Double salesForecast;

    @JsonProperty("location_shipping_forecast")
    private Double locationShippingForecast;

    @JsonProperty("roll_previous_month")
    private Double rollPreviousMonth;

    @JsonProperty("total_sold")
    private Double totalSold;

    @JsonProperty("total_sold_roll_in")
    private Double totalSoldRollIn;

    @JsonProperty("shipped_in_month")
    private Double shippedInMonth;

    @JsonProperty("sales_rolled_next_month")
    private Double salesRolled_next_month;

    @JsonProperty("left_to_ship")
    private Double leftToShip;

    @JsonProperty("unsold_allocated_capacity")
    private Double unsoldAllocatedCapacity;

    @JsonProperty("unallocated_capacity")
    private Double unallocatedCapacity;

    @JsonProperty("unshipped_capacity")
    private Double unshippedCapacity;

    @JsonProperty("previous_3_months_forecast")
    private Double previous3MonthsForecast;

    @JsonProperty("forecast_accuracy")
    private Double forecastAccuracy;

    @JsonProperty("total_unsold")
    private Double totalUnsold;

    @JsonProperty("total_projected_shipments")
    private Double totalProjectedShipments;

    @JsonProperty("initial_inventory")
    private Double initialInventory;

    @JsonProperty("total_inbounds")
    private Double totalInbounds;

    @JsonProperty("last_year_shipped_in_month")
    private Double lastYearShippedInMonth;

    @JsonProperty("fiscal_year")
    private String fiscalYear;


}
```

Can anybody tell me what am i doing wrong?

I am receiving the data from the source and when i am trying to map using @SqlResultSetMapping, i am getting this Hibernate mapping error after migrating to 3.0.1.  Note: This was working in spring 2.7 .

Comment: I assume you mean spring boot 2.7/3.0.1?  spring 3.0.1 was released was released in 2010.

Comment: currently i am using springboot 3.0.1 in which i am getting this error

Comment: spring and spring boot are not the same thing.  Try turning on sql logging and see what's getting generated, you have a lot of indirection in there, it's not clear what's going on.

Comment: this is the pom.xml i am using

Answer (score 1):

Check this other answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36109273

I do not know what changed going into Spring Boot v3.0.1, but you can try attaching your `@SqlResultSetMapping` annotation to one of your `@Entity` classes in order to be detected.  I do not know why it used to work with `@MappedSuperclass` before and now it doesn't (maybe it's a bug?).

If you wanted to avoid using an entity, you can so something like:

```java
@SqlResultSetMapping(
        name = "MessageDTO",
        classes = @ConstructorResult(targetClass = MessageDTO.class, columns = {
                @ColumnResult(name = "message_body", type = String.class),
                @ColumnResult(name = "created_date", type = OffsetDateTime.class)
        })
)
@Embeddable
public static class SQLMappingConfigEntity {
    /* this dummy Embeddable class allows SqlResultSetMapping annotation to be picked up */
}
```

In this example, MessageDTO would be your DTO. It must have with a constructor will all arguments.